# Blackberry 10: Android Runtime & JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

Is JNI supported on the BlackBerry 10 Android Runtime? I would like to execute native c code in my android app which I'd like to deploy on the blackberry 10 os. In my android app, I use JNI to handle callbacks from the native c code to the java code. Is this supported on the bb10 android runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I could find is this thread: [Any plans for supporting Android Native Code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Any-plans-for-supporting-Android-Native-Code/td-p/1563397) which doesn't appear to have an official response.

My guess is that 'no' Android NDK won't be supported as Blackberry 10 already has a Native C/C++ SDK for those pure C/C++ apps (games, other performance heavy apps) or if you want UI widgets to use the C++/Qt/Cascades framework.

Edit: Found the official response under the Unsupported Software Features: 'Apps that utilize native code bundled into their APK file'. [Blackberry 10 Unsupported Software Features for Android](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_software_features.html). So its a definite no for the Blackberry 10.1 and lower runtime using Android Gingerbread.

2013-12-05 Update: Looks like Blackberry 10.2 will be supporting Jelly Bean and have general support for Android JNI via the Android NDK with some limitations. See [Blackberry Android Native Support](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupported_api_android_ndk.html)