# JNI in Blackberry10

Tags: java-native-interface, blackberry-10

I would like to know if it was possible to use JNI for an BB10 app. I'm kinda new with this thing and I saw somewhere that is possible.

Because I've an android app but I need to had some special features to make it run properly on BB10 and for that I need to use JNI.

Is it possible ? If yes, is it possible to find a sample or some doc about it somewhere ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558356/blackberry-10-android-runtime-jni

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking about running an Android appliction on BB10. Support for JNI does not exist on any of the current official BB10 versions (up to and including 10.2.0). However version 10.2.1 includes a completely different Android runtime that is able to run APK directly including applications that use JNI. I haven't seen any official documentation of this yet however.